# Json:Type information is unavailable, and the target object is not a primitive

Tags: java, json, collections, gson

I am having an `Employee` class

```
class Employee {
String name;

Identity id;

List<Address> addressList;
}
```

i am getting json format String from resttemplate for employee object.When I am trying to convert the json format string to object using `gson.fromJson()`.I am getting `"Type information is unavailable, and the target object is not a primitive"` error.

Even if i go for a token type list that will be the solution to convert list.

Comment: Can you share your serializer code?